# Codeigniter: Uploading image through Ajax and storing in db

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using CI 3.0.1 was uploading and inserting image to db successfully before i used ajax, i guess trying to do it with ajax i'm missing something which isn't even sending data to upload maybe because we have to use **multipart()** in form while in ajax we are just sending data direct to controller, another thing i don't know how to receive the variable in response 
my Ajax request function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 alert("thirddddddddd");
        $('#btnsubmit').click(function() 
        {
            alert("i got submitted");
            event.preventDefault();
             var userfile = $("input#pfile").val();
                        alert("uploading");
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/do_upload', //how to receive var here ?
            type: 'POST',
             cache: false,
             data: {userfile: userfile},
            success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $('.img_pre').attr('src', "<?php echo base_url().'uploads/' ?>");
                $('.dltbtn').hide();
            },
            error: function(data)
            {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(data);
               alert("Error :"+data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And my controller Upload's function **do_upload** is:

```
 public function do_upload()
    {

            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/'; #$this->config->item('base_url').
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('layouts/header');
                    $this->load->view('home_page', $error);
                    $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    $imagedata = $this->input->post('uerfile');

                    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                    $id =  $session_data['id'];


                    $result = $this->model_edit->update_dp($id, $imagedata);

                    $image_name = $result->images;

                    $this->session->set_userdata('image', $image_name);

                    echo json_encode($name = array('image' => $image_name));

                    // $image_name = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                    // $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    // redirect("account");
            }
    }
```

Now image is not even going to **uploads** folder, if any other file is needed tell me i'll post it here. Thanks

Comment: is the uploads folder writable? is it located at public root?

Comment: yes its in root, as i said everything was working fine when i was doing it without ajax

Comment: Javascript can't actually see the contents of the file in the file input, so it can't read the contents in order to send the data to the server via Ajax. There are workarounds for this, like submitting the form  to an iframe on the page to avoid reload.

Comment: @ShamSUP can you direct me to any reference for that?

Comment: You cannot simply get the value of file like other inputs

Comment: @Poria actually that was stupid of me :p i just tried that after trying long time to get data with `$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());`

Comment: I was talking about the jquery  var userfile = $("input#pfile").val(); it is wrong, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send file data using `$("input#pfile").val();`

```
var len = $("#pfile").files.length;
    var file = new Array();
    var formdata = new FormData();
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        file[i] = $("input#pfile").files[i];
        formdata.append("file"+i, file[i]);
    }
```

and send `formdata` as data from ajax

Hope it helps !

Comment: so it is made to specifically get the data of mulipart form ?

Comment: Yes you need to use files to get file using jquery

Comment: Apparently I was mistaken, and it can be done via Ajax using FormData, [blog post from treehouse](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax). Also view the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: after doing that how will we send data ? `data : { formdata : formdata },`

Comment: Read it out  http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Simple-File-Upload-with-Ajax

Comment: @Poria after we process the sent data, how do we retrieve data inform of variable ?

Comment: i have an error though `account:134 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: check the id of the input file element

Comment: Also check if you have <form enctype="multipart/form-data" > in your form tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111615/discussion-between-habib-rehman-and-poria).

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below ajax code

```
var formData = new FormData($('#formid'));
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/do_upload',
    data: formData ,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

The file contents may not send through ajax as per your code. Try with the attributes mentioned in above code.